# Adding numbers of a list together

Tags: java

```
3
100 8
15 245
1945 54
```

The numbers above, first is the amount of pairs, and then I want to add line by line, and have been stuck for hours. Can someone please help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class sumInLoops2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your variables: ");
        int cases = in.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
            list1.add(in.nextInt());
            list2.add(in.nextInt());
            System.out.println(list1);
            System.out.println(list2);
         }
```

Comment: You have code for reading the values, but it's unclear what it is you want to do with them. You don't show any attempt at "adding numbers" (using `+` operator), so it's difficult to see which part is troubling you.

Comment: And where exactly have you been stuck?  We're happy to help you over the hurdle you can't get up yourself, but we won't write this assignment for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things. If you don't need to store the read values, only output the sum, then you don't need all the lists.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sumInLoops2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     //   ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     //   ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your variables: ");
        int cases = in.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
            int val1 = in.nextInt();
            int val2 = in.nextInt();
            int sum = val1 + val2;
            System.out.println(val1  + " + " + val2 + " = " + sum );
         }
    }
}
```

If you need to store the results, make a helper object (eg `LineSum`) with properties `val1`, `val2`, `sum`, and put that in one output list.

Answer (score 0):

As @thst said stated, if there is no need to store the data being inputted by the user, don't over complicate things and just output the result you need. However if your intention is to learn how to output matching number pairs within those separate lists.

Whenever you want to access a item inside a List you use the lists get() method which returns the item at that index. So in your case to print out the matching pairs added together.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++)
{
    int num1 = list1.get(i);
    int num2 = list2.get(i);
    int sum = num1 + num2;

    System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A fast example using `Java8`(best way,give it a try):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java8Way {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create a Scanner Object
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your variables(separated by a space): ");

        //what the following is doing

        //Arrays.asList(in.nextLine().split(" ")->Splits the line that user gave to individual strings
                                                  //makes a list from them using method asList(..); from 
                                                  //Arrays Class

        //mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)-> makes a stream an map each string to and integer

        //sum()->a special kind of reduce function which sums all the Integer elements

        System.out.println("Your sum is...:"+Arrays.asList(in.nextLine().split(" ")).stream()
                                                                                    .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                                                                                    .sum());
    }

}
```